# Wordpress admin_menu

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create an admin menu for my plugin.

```
$my_hook = add_menu_page( 
                   'String',
                   'String', 
                   'manage_options',
                   'mypage&type=mytype', 
                   'my_function'
                    );
```

If i try to acces the page now at

```
wp-admin/admin.php?page=mypage&type=mytype
```

via the menu, i get: "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.". Is it not possible to include GET parameters like &type=mytype in the menu entry?

Thanks.

Comment: It cannot be a variable parameter anyway, so **why do you need** to include such parameter?

Comment: Im not sure i understand. Why would i not want to include such a parameter? The thing is, i can do it everywhere in workdpress except for the menu.

Comment: I'm not trying to provide a solution to make the [`$menu_slug`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page#Parameters) to work the way you're trying... What I don't understand is: if we remove the parameter, the plugin page works as expected. What difference it possibly makes to have this parameter or not? As an end result for your plugin's page? I mean: `type` will always be `mytype` when you arrive at the plugin's page... What else could happen?

Comment: I know that it's not very clear why i would want this, and it's a little hard to explain. Basically i have many menu entries, but i want to route to the same page, and use the GET parameters to decide on some action. So all menu entries related to 'foo' would route to admin.php?page=foo&action=bar. It is not strictly necessary, i'm just wondering if it could work...

Comment: Now I see the big picture ;) I'll wrap an answer. Tip: you'll find much more plugin developers at the sister site [wordpress.se].

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell for sure why trying to add parameters to a Menu or Submenu slug invalidates the generated link. But the `$menu_slug` is used in both functions [`add_menu_page`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L893) and [`add_submenu_page()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L998) to search of a PHP file (instead of the function callback) and to build the plugin URL.
Trying to add the extra operators `?` or `&` does not play nice, ie, it doesn't work either with `plugin_basename` or `get_plugin_page_hookname`.

Here's a workaround to use the same callback function with various top level admin menus. The URL's will be:

- http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=myplugin1
- http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=myplugin2

and the callback function checks for `$_GET['page']`.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'menu_so_17406309' );

function menu_so_17406309()
{
    add_menu_page( 
        'First',
        'First', 
        'manage_options',
        'myplugin1',
        'callback_so_17406309'
    );
    add_menu_page( 
        'Second',
        'Second', 
        'manage_options',
        'myplugin2',
        'callback_so_17406309'
    );
}

function callback_so_17406309() 
{
    switch( $_GET['page'] ) 
    {
        case 'myplugin1':
            echo 'first page';
        break;
        case 'myplugin2':
            echo 'second page';
        break;
        default:
            echo 'error';
        break;
    }   
}
```

*Relevant [search query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2badd_menu_page%20%2bmenu_slug) at WordPress Answers.*

Comment: Yes, that would work. However, it's not exactly what i'm looking for. I will answer my own question, but thanks for your time and tips!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to add new menu item

```
$my_hook = add_menu_page( 
               'String',
               'String', 
               'manage_options',
               '?page=pagename', 
               'my_function'
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

For `manage_options` is a requiered option that specify the capability for this menu to be displayed to the user. [more details...](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page)

you put the role wich has the sufficient permissions to access or manage this page.

You can try this:

```
$my_hook = add_menu_page( 
   'String',
   'String', 
   'administrator',
   'mypage&type=mytype', 
   'my_function'
);
```